# Can somebody tell me why the finite duration of the unit impulse response of this system is M+1?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, signal-processing

This has to do with FIR Filters. I got the question pictured below wrong on a quiz and I'm not exactly sure why. It seemed simple because in my professor's lecture notes (also pictured below), the summation in the unit impulse response went from 0 to M. I assumed the answer to this question would be the same. Is the answer M+1 because of the causality of the system?

[Quiz Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM29S.png)

[Lecture Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1WxL.jpg)

Comment: Directly replacing $x[n] = \delta[n]$ we get $y[n]$ is the summation of $M+1$ deltas from $0$ to $M$...